# How to highlight a column for 500ms when it's data changes. Need to highlight it green/red based on whether increased or decreased in value from last

Tags: rxjs, angular6, angular-material2

I've included angular material table in my new project and want the table to keep track of each column's data when it changes. If the data value is increased then flash the column in green color and if decreased then in red color for say 500ms and then return to normal state.

I've tried doing that with keeping track of the last data in my code itself but it is not looking an optimized solution. Whether some directive or any material  functionality can help me in that?

### HTML

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="time">
    <mat-header-cell class="text-text" *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="text-text" *matCellDef="let row"> <b>{{row['time']}}</b> </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="valueA">
    <mat-header-cell class="text-text" *matHeaderCellDef> valueA </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="text-text" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row['valueA']}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="valueB">
    <mat-header-cell class="text-text" *matHeaderCellDef> valueB </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="text-text" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row['valueB']}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="bg-table-odd-row"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'bg-table-even-row': i%2 == 0, 'bg-table-odd-row': i%2 != 0}"></mat-row>
```

### TS

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-table',
  templateUrl: './my-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-table.component.styl'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MyTableComponent {
  displayedColumns = ['time', 'valueA', 'valueB'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  private tableData: any = [];

  @Input()
  set data(value) {
    if(value) {
        this.tableData = [...value];
        this.refresh();
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
  }

  private refresh() {
    this.dataSource.data = this.tableData;
  }
}
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: @FanCheung I've added the code. Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the data setter and hook your logic there

```
@Input()
  set data(value) {
    if(value) {
        const newData=[...value];
         this.tableData = [...value];
        this.refresh();
        this.flashClass=''
        if(this.tableData.length>newData.length)
            this.flashClass='green-flash'
        if(this.tableData.length>newData.length)
            this.flashClass='red-flash'
    }
  };
```

apply the class to your html

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="time" [ngClass]="flashClass">
    <mat-header-cell class="text-text" *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="text-text" *matCellDef="let row"> <b>{{row['time']}}</b> </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

animations css

```
.green-flash {
    -webkit-animation-name: flash-animation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;

    animation-name: flash-animation;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes flash-animation {  
    from { background: none; }
    to   { background: green; }
}
```